# How to store an object's state when a service is restarted

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-lifecycle

My application launches a service which spawns a thread. The thread does some polling every 5 seconds. Android can restart my service as it sees fit. I am trying to store the polling thread so when the service is restarted it can use the existing polling thread.

Here's the onStartCommand() method:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    if(intent == null)
    {
        Log.d("screener", "onStartCommand was called with null intent. System must've killed and restarted service...?");
    }
    else
    {
        processToMonitor = intent.getStringExtra("com.screener.processToMonitor");
        Log.d("screener", "onStartCommand was called");

    }

    if(pollThread == null)
    {
        poller = new Poller(this, wakeLock, processToMonitor);
        pollThread = new Thread(poller);
        pollThread.start();
        Log.d("screenon", "polling thread was not already running. Going to start it");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("screener", "polling thread has already been running. Not going to restart it");
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

It appears that when the passed Intent object is null, this signifies the service has been restartedm so I can successfully detect this scenario. The object I would like to store is poller (or pollerThread which encapsulates the poller). I have tried making it static which didn't work. I also overrode Application and stored an instance in there, but it is still not persisted.

So, how do I store my object when the service is restarted? Or, do I accept that Android cleans everything up and simply restart the thread?

Comment: i would say that your service is restarted if your process is killed, which would be consistent with your thread disappearing.

Comment: Ok, so in that case even the Application object is recreated so there's no chance of storing an object other than persistance storage?

Comment: Nope, use the sdcard and store it as file or use `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to store the thread? Let it "die" and once your service is restarted a new poller thread will start.

Comment: Well, I didn't know for sure that it would die and didn't want to start another if the original one was already running